# Prestashop Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello I Install Prestashop 1.6.1.17 on localhost successfully but I get in homepage this error

Fatal error:

> Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   6144 bytes) in
>   C:\AppServ\www\prestashop\tools\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatelexer.php
>   on line 825

I increased memory_limit at php.ini but the problem doesn't solved

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and I want to share that with you
when I edit php.ini I put memory_limit 2048M but also the error doesn't solve

The solution is:
I add `ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');`
in config/config.inc.php file